# c++ Armadillo: what does "norm_dot" do?

Tags: c++, armadillo, dot-product

What is this function doing? It states it is the normalized version of the dot product, which I presumed meant

```
func norm_dot(A,B) = dot(A,B) / ||B||^2
```

but

```
vec A(3,1) ; A.randu() ;
vec B(3,1) ; B.randu() ;

double dot1 = dot(A,B) /  arma::accu(arma::square(B)) ;

double dot2 = norm_dot(A,B) ;
```

dot1 != dot2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normalised dot product would be

```
dot(A,B)/(|A||B|)
```

Your expression only works for |A|=|B|

Comment: My bad...thanks...I am implementing a paper and been doing a load of dot(A,B)/B^2 type operations and quickly saw the norm_dot in the Arma docs when looking for something else, and thought that is the operation I am doing (which I am not).